# How to Get Error Response from ngResource $resource query

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, ngresource, angular-controller

hi working on my first angular project and i've run into this problem with not being able to see a value from the service im using in one of my controllers.

also the characterService.query() is fine just the value of errorMessage is not showing up

thanks for your help

Service:

```
angular.module('characterResource',['ngResource'])

.factory('characterService',['$resource',function($resource){
var self = this;

self.errorMessage = false;

return $resource('http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/characters?limit=90&apikey=APIKEY',null, {

    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: false,
      transformResponse: function(data) {
        return angular.fromJson(data).data;
      },
      interceptor:{
        responseError:function(error){
            console.log(error);
            self.errorMessage = true;
        }
      }
    }

});

}]);
```

controller:

```
angular.module('CharactersCtrl', []).controller('CharactersController',['characterService', function(characterService) {
var self = this;
self.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
self.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
//self.search  = ' ';     // set the default search/filter term

self.errorMessage = characterService.errorMessage;
console.log(characterService.errorMessage);

self.init = function(){
    self.getCharacters();
}

self.getCharacters = function(){
    self.characters = characterService.query();
}

self.init();

}]);
```

Comment: create a plunker to replicate the issue , add your view code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use an error interceptor. To get the error response from an `ngResource` query, use the `.catch` method on its `$promise` property.

```
self.getCharacters = function(){
    self.characters = characterService.query();
    self.characters.$promise.catch( function(errorResponse) {
        console.log(errorResponse);
        self.errorMessage = true;
    });     
}
```

From the Docs:

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in [resolve section of $routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
> On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the resource property.

--[AngularJS $resource Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)